# SQLite "where" return 21

Tags: swift, sqlite

I'm trying to get from the *table* all the the *rows* that have same *USERID*
I thinking that something wrong with *sqlite3_prepare_v2* or with *sqlite3_bind_text*,
to debugging this *code*,  I've printed

```
print(sqlite3_step(sqlite3_stmt))
print(sqlite3_step(sqlite3_stmt))
```

In the first time printed as *101* and the second time printed *21*

However "SELECT * from IMAGE_TABLE" working good

Thanks!

```
  var sqlite3_stmt: OpaquePointer? = nil

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,"SELECT * from IMAGE_TABLE where USERID = ?;",-1,&sqlite3_stmt,nil) == SQLITE_OK){


        sqlite3_bind_text(sqlite3_stmt, 1, uid.cString(using: .utf8), 1,nil);

        while(sqlite3_step(sqlite3_stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){


            let imageDescription = String(validatingUTF8:sqlite3_column_text(sqlite3_stmt,0))
            let imageUrl = String(validatingUTF8:sqlite3_column_text(sqlite3_stmt,2))
            let imageName = String(validatingUTF8:sqlite3_column_text(sqlite3_stmt,3))
            let pic = Picture(imageDescription!,imageUrl!,imageName!)
            picList.append(pic)
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `101` is `SQLITE_DONE`, meaning there are no more rows to return, i.e. there was no record matching your `WHERE` clause. The `21` is `SQLITE_MISUSE`, because you called `sqlite3_step` to retrieve the next record after it just told you there were no more records.

There are two problems here:

1. Your `?` placeholder is being bound with `sqlite3_bind_text`, but you're using `1` for the fourth parameter. That means that it will only use the first character of the `uid` string. I suspect you meant to use `-1`, a negative value, which instructs `sqlite3_bind_text` to use the entire string up to the zero terminator.
2. You also should use `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` in your `sqlite3_bind_text` call. So, if you haven't already, define those constants:

   ```
   internal let SQLITE_STATIC = unsafeBitCast(0, to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
   internal let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = unsafeBitCast(-1, to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
   ```

   And then use that in your `sqlite3_bind_text` call:

   ```
   guard sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, uid.cString(using: .utf8), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) == SQLITE_OK else {
       ...
   }
   ```

   This instructs SQLite to make its own copy of that C-string, because you have no assurances regarding the lifespan of your own C-string.

Comment: thanks a lot for your fast response i changed it to 1 just to check something ,i put it back to -1 and sometime im get 1 row sometime 2 and sometime nothing although i have more rows that contains same userid

Comment: @user7024226 - Retrieving records from SQLite is extremely robust. If you're really getting a different number of records than you expected, then the problem rests elsewhere. Perhaps some of the `USERID` column values are not quite what you expected (e.g. some of them have spaces or other not easily seen whitespace). Perhaps the capitalization doesn't match. Perhaps you're calling this from some background dispatch queue and aren't synchronizing the interactions from the various threads. We can't say without more information.

Comment: @user7024226 - By the way, when you say you're getting different number of records, I assume that's without the `print(sqlite3_step())` statements. The issue is that if you have a `print(sqlite3_step())`, that not only returns the "is there another record", but it actually returns that record. So if you have two `print(sqlite3_step())` before your `while` loop, you're going to have discarded two rows. Perhaps that's not your issue here, but it's a mistake I've seen others make here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I removed the prints its was only to debuggin what sql returns , i dont thinks that something wrong with the tabale because i openned it with browser and all the values looks good i will try to search more reasons . I would like to know only if the querey code are right?

Comment: @user7024226 - It's largely correct, except make sure to use `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` because you have no assurances as to the lifespan of that pointer. I can reproduce your problem by using `nil` (which is equivalent to `SQLITE_STATIC`). See my expanded answer.